# increase the breaks in legend presentation in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that I would like to create a heat map using ggplot2, my data frame looks like this:

```
dput(head(x,50))
structure(list(DAY = structure(c(15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 
15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 
15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 
15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 
15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 
15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 
15765), class = "Date"), Time = c("00:14", "00:29", "00:44", 
"00:59", "01:14", "01:29", "01:44", "01:59", "02:14", "02:29", 
"02:44", "02:59", "03:14", "03:29", "03:44", "03:59", "04:14", 
"04:29", "04:44", "04:59", "05:14", "05:29", "05:44", "05:59", 
"06:14", "06:29", "06:44", "06:59", "07:14", "07:29", "07:44", 
"07:59", "08:14", "08:29", "08:44", "08:59", "09:14", "09:29", 
"09:44", "09:59", "10:14", "10:29", "10:44", "10:59", "11:14", 
"11:29", "11:44", "11:59", "12:14", "12:29"), CPU = c(12.9428571428571, 
8, 8.03333333333333, 7.83333333333333, 6.9, 7.1, 6.9, 5.2, 5.66666666666667, 
7, 6.46666666666667, 5.93333333333333, 5.9, 6.4, 4.73333333333333, 
4.2, 8.13333333333333, 11.8333333333333, 16.1, 22.1, 27.2, 28.2333333333333, 
25.3666666666667, 26.1666666666667, 24, 23.2, 24.1, 24.7666666666667, 
27, 27.8333333333333, 28.6, 30.6333333333333, 38.3, 33.5, 36.9, 
41.7333333333333, 50.0666666666667, 46.9666666666667, 45.6666666666667, 
45.1333333333333, 52.9333333333333, 49.9, 47.8666666666667, 47.7, 
55.5, 50, 48.8333333333333, 48.2333333333333, 53.6666666666667, 
50.1379310344828)), .Names = c("DAY", "Time", "CPU"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I do the following, I only see some dots in the tiles, it is mostly white. I need to have square colors in my heat map.

```
ggplot(x, aes(DATE, Time, fill=CPU)) + geom_tile() + theme_bw()
 + scale_x_datetime(breaks = "2 weeks", labels=date_format("%b %d, %Y"))
 + scale_y_datetime(breaks="2 hours", labels=date_format("%H:%M"))
 + guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 1)) 
+ scale_fill_gradientn(name="CPU Utilization", colours=c("#F0FFFF","#AEEEEE","#ADD8E6","#87CEFA","#00FF00","#E4F224","#C9821E", "#FF0000", "#FF0000"), value=c(0,0.19,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.81,1),
limits=c(0,100), breaks = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `scale_fill_gradientn()` to get fill values with colors you need. With argument `limits=c(0,100)` you will get legend in this range. Then with arguments `values=` and `colours=` you set distribution of colors. In my example scales starts with darkgreen color then goes to green, changes to red, then goes to darkred and again red. At the end again is green and darkgreen. With `values=` I set points in scale of 0 to 1 where colors should change - start with 0, red color starts at 0.2 and ends at 0.8 and so on.

```
ggplot(y, aes(DAY, Time, fill=CPU)) + geom_tile() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = "2 weeks", labels=date_format("%b %d, %Y")) + 
  scale_colour_discrete(name="15 Minute CPU") + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(name="CPU Utilization",
        colours=c("darkgreen","green","red","darkred","red","green","darkgreen"),
        values=c(0,0.19,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.81,1),
        limits=c(0,100),
        breaks = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100))
```

[image]

Comment: @Diszis Elferts, I've updated my original post with your suggestions but still having some issues. I need to fill the squares with colors not working for me.

Comment: @user1471980 In your code there should be values=c() instead of value=c() in scale_fill_gradientn()

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I have one quick question. Not clear on this: values=c(0,0.19,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.81,1),
I have 9 different colors for each of these - breaks = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100). When I use your values, graph does not look right. I see a lot more occurence of CPU greater than 60 than actually is. Any ideas, how I can address this?

Comment: those values  are positions of colors for gradient ends. Maybe it is better to cut your cpu values with cut() and use manual scale